# MySQL command line syntax select column without FROM statement

Tags: mysql, command-line

It's very simple to select a column using common-known command line syntax like

```
mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD -e 'SELECT columnname FROM databasename.tablename' ;
```

But is it possible to make the same select without FROM statement ? Something like

```
mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD -e 'SELECT databasename.tablename.[columname]' ;
```

Comment: The obvious question would be: have you tried it, and if yes, what was the result?

Comment: I tried many versions - or wrong SQL syntax or Unknown table. This is why I asked here - is it possible ? maybe no solution at all.

Comment: Then maybe the answer is that it cannot be done, the MySQL manual also implicates this: "MySQL does not require FROM DUAL if no tables are referenced." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: The matter of my question is about a trick with syntax, is it possible to use a specific syntax to explain mysql command line without FROM what to select.

Comment: The answer to that is no. Every programming language has rules and this is one of sql's

Comment: As already suggested, as the manual implicates and as @P.Salmon says, no you cannot use such a trick.

Comment: Negative answer is also the answer for knowledge :)